# how to use client browser scrolling to load the html contents as did in facebook home page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I m new to web designing I want help from u guys

I have to build a html page which loads the all profile details from the mysql DB server.
but DB contains about 1000 persons profile details . I need to display  all that detail. im using php scripting as server side programing and I have the code for retrieve the records from DB and that php code will generate html page too but it loads all 1000 persons profile.

**but I want to load first 50 records and later onscrolling, load next 50 records so on in that same page as in facebook feeds page**

the php code is I used is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="img_container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul>
                <?php include 'connection.php';
                    $query= "select name, orgn, des ,email ,photo_path from profile_info ;";
                    $result=mysql_query($query);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="tooltip" href="#"><img src="<?php echo $row['photo_path']?>" alt="name"/>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Name</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Organisation</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['orgn']?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Designation</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['des']?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>e-Mail</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                     </tbody>
                                </table> 
                            </div>  
                        </a>
                    </li>  
                    <?php } ?>  


                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

I just knows very basics of html, js, jquery ,css and php and also I gone through following Answer from that  I cant able to do what I really required.

[Lazy load from database as user scrolls down page (similiar to Twitter and Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993528/lazy-load-from-database-as-user-scrolls-down-page-similiar-to-twitter-and-faceb)

plz help me regards this plz plz.... im not a good programmer I just need this to my academic project.. pleas help :-)

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google for 'Lazy Load' and i found this jQuery Plugin.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Simply download and upload the package (aswell as jQuery) to your server.

Add the following to your `<head>` section:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Give your images a class such as `.lazy`, this allows the Plugin to bind to the images:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="img/example.jpg" width="640" height="480">
```

The initialize the plugin using the following function:

```
$(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

Comment: Better suited for a comment, or expand upon it with an example or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax to load data from php instead of directly displaying it. You ajax request should send number of rows to load each time, to your php page which will then return those many requests in some format preferably JSON. Then when ajax receives that response parse json and load content in "div" element. Thats the basic structure. Now to load data dynamically you can use jQuery's `scroll()` function to determine when the last element is reached. Then your ajax function is called in which request next set of rows. Since you are new, I recommend reading the following:

[jQuery Offset turotial](http://api.jquery.com/offset)
[jQuery Scroll Top](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop)
[jQuery Scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll)

They will help. Good Luck :)